# DockbarX: Adding more buttons eg main menu or shutdown

Tags: dockbarx

How might I add a shutdown button in DockBarX? I see from [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/window-switcher-dockbarx-adds-media-player-buttons-dock-helpers/)
that I seem to be able to have a "start menu" in dockbarx? How can I do that? I think it will have a shutdown button in there already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's dockbarx running in the gnome-panel. The button is the gnomenu applet, not a part of dockbarx.

There is no real way to add a start menu to dockbarx but the start menu cardapio can be launched at the mouse cursor with the command "cardapio show-near-mouse". If you make a custom launcher with alacarte or whatever and drag it drag it to DockbarX you get a start menu. It will look a bit weird since DockbarX can't register when programs with no normal windows have started so the "wait" look will stay for 10 seconds after you'd clicked the button but it will work normally otherwise.